# Vb.net sendkeys & target

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

When using `Sendkeys` with vb.net, is it possible to tell if the target of the `Sendkeys` has changed between sendings?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No.  But if you have control over the target, you can control where the SendKeys goes by Activating your target before the SendKeys.